# Error en la configuración de CORS AWS

Tags: aws, cors

estoy tratando de configurar cors en AWS pero al hacerlo me da un error la configuración es la siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

y el error que me da es el siguiente: 
*Error desconocido

Se ha producido un error inesperado.

Respuesta de API

Expected params.CORSConfiguration.CORSRules to be an Array*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasa que AWS ahora espera eso en un JSON ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587688/236345)) para la nueva interfaz de S3 Bucket. Si se devuelven a la vieja, va a seguir aceptando el XML.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

La opción B, que también [he visto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939041/236345) como recomendación, es que debas añadir HEAD

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod> <!-- añadir ésto -->
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```